# Not able to show foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a Post and Comments sections, I managed to show all the posts in one page, now I'm trying to show the comments under each post. In my model, I have connected both tables and in my function I am able to view the post and comments when I use `dd();` this is my result:

[image: dd();]

I am not sure if I'm calling the comment part correctly in my Views because I am getting error :

> Property [activity_post_comments] does not exist on this collection instance.
>   (View: C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rsapp\resources\views\pages\timeline.blade.php)

My function:

```
public function timeline()
{
    $activityposts = ActivityPost::with('activity_post_comment')
                                ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                                ->paginate(100);

    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(100);

    // dd($activityposts);

    return view('pages.timeline')
            ->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('activityposts', $activityposts);
}
```

View:

```
@if(count($activityposts) > 0)
    @foreach($activityposts as $activitypost)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!--
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a>
        <h4>Bootply Editor &amp; Code Library</h4></div>
        -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
                <img src="../storage/user_image/{{ $activitypost->user->user_image }}" width="28px" height="28px">
                <b>{{ $activitypost->user->firstname }} {{ $activitypost->user->lastname }}</b>
                <span class="pull-right">{{ $activitypost->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}</span>
            </p>
            <!--
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <hr>
            -->
            {{ $activitypost->status_update }}
            <hr>
            <div class="well"> 
                {{ $activitypost->activity_post_comments->activity_post_comments }};
            </div>
            <hr>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ action('PagesController@storecomments', $activitypost->id) }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('activity_post_comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <!-- <label for="activity_post_comments" class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label> -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input id="activity_post_comments" type="text" class="form-control" name="activity_post_comments" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('activity_post_comments'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('activity_post_comments') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
{{$activityposts->links()}}
@else
<p>No new activity from users</p>
@endif
```

Here is where I'm not sure :

```
{{ $activitypost->activity_post_comment->activity_post_comments }};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `activity_post_comment` would be a collection, you need to loop through the same to get individual instances.

```
@foreach ($activitypost->activity_post_comment as $comment)
<p>{{ $comment->activity_post_comments }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

as linktoahref pointed out, the thing you're not sure is correct.
The relationship between $activitypost and $activity_post_comment is 1-n,
or $activitypost will has a collection of $activity_post_comment,
so when working with collection you could use for-loop or other convenient helper method.
for-loop could be

```
@foreach ($activitypost->activity_post_comment as $comment)
<p>{{ $comment->activity_post_comments }}</p>
@endforeach
```

or if you just want an array of activity_post_comments

```
$activitypost->activity_post_comment->pluck('activity_post_comments')
```